# Worklight - overloading NSURLConnection delegate method

Tags: ios, ibm-mobilefirst

I am working on an iOS app that is communicating with a Worklight server thanks to the iOS SDK provided by Worklight.

I would like to integrate the AppConnect SDK (MDM) to the project in order to do some tunneling on communications.

For this, I have to overload an [NSURLConnectionDelegate method](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSURLConnectionDelegate/connection:willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:) to add some AppConnect-related certificate configuration to an HTTP request :

```
- (void) connection: (NSURLConnection *)connection willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge;
```

The problem is that NSURLConnections and NSURLRequests are encapsulated by the Worklight iOS library : the method that I use to make calls is

```
[[WLClient sharedInstance] invokeProcedure:myInvocation withDelegate:self options:serviceOptions];
```

So I can't see the NSURLConnections and NSURLRequests, and I can't overload the NSURLConnectionDelegate method...

That's why I would like to know : is it possible to overload the HTTP behavior of the Worklight iOS library in this way ? And if it is possible, how can I do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to add header, you can use the options in invokeProcedure.
In case you need more complicated things, I would suggest using NSURLProtocol -> https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLProtocol_Class/index.html

Comment: It is not only a header.And NSURLProtocol doesn't help a lot because, again, I have to use the worklight library, and it entirely handles HTTP requests.

Comment: NSURLProtocol let you change any request, so you can keep working with Worklight but change the outgoing request so it will fit your needs.